# how to make many websites that use the same files or different ones if they changes in some domains using php

Tags: php, api, subdomain

i build a web site and i need to make him for about 30 domains or sub sub domains ( this 30 websites is **copied from base copy that means they have almost the same code and the same design**  ) but may be in some time i need to change some page content in one of these 30 copy and make another change to another one and if i didn't change any file in one of these copies i need it to take it from base copy

finally i am searching if there are an easy way to edit this web sites or manage it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same server for all the 30 websites then you can have virtual host for each site and keep [DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) same for all the domains.
What this will do is your domain name will be different but it takes same code from common place(base website) for all the websites.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not related with php.
My recommendation is to use **Addon Domains**.
In this way you will have a Single Hosting Package but you can host multiple domains in the same server. So lets say these are your domains:

> /public_html/domain1.com /public_html/domain2.com
>   /public_html/domain2.com

You can create a base directory: /public_html/base

Now in the domains you can include the php files from this base directory like this:

```
require_once("/public_html/base/include.php");
require_once("/public_html/base/mysql.php");
```

Make sure when you use this way you may need to setup php.ini variable of: open_basedir:

> open_basedir string Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the
>   specified directory-tree, including the file itself. This directive is
>   NOT affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.